# Header and footer on jspdf do not work properly

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, jspdf

I'm trying to make a conversion from a html to pdf on html script tag, it should be done like that so we don't need to use a server just to make reports. Its not a web app, it will be used in other way that does no matter to the question. I can not make the header and the footer appear properly on the top and bottom of the page, the lack of documentation and the break change on the jspdf to change "fromhtml" to "html" make things a lot harder. After a lot of tries, I become with the following code, but it seems the loop that set the header and footer end before the promise is resolved. I just need to convert a html to a pdf with the header in all pages and I cant use a server or the terminal to that, I'm open to use other libs or languages, following the code (the html is just HTML):

```
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>jsPDF - Create PDFs with HTML5 JavaScript Library</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta name="description" content="" />
  <meta name="author" content="" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/2.5.1/jspdf.umd.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/1.4.1/html2canvas.min.js">
  </script>
 

<script>

  function convertHTMLtoPDF() {
    const { jsPDF } = window.jspdf;

    let doc = new jsPDF("p", "pt", "a4");
    let pdfjs = document.querySelector("#divID");
    let header = document.querySelector("#header");
    let footer = document.querySelector("#footer");

    doc
      .html(pdfjs, {
        callback: function (doc) {},
        x: 12,
        y: 12,
        margin: [60, 10, 40, 10],
      })
      .then(() => {
        const totalPages = doc.internal.getNumberOfPages();

        let cont = 1;

        const addHeaderAndFooterToPage = () => {
          doc.setPage(cont);
          doc.setFontSize(12);

          doc.setFontSize(12);
          doc.html(header, { x: 10, y: 10 }).then(() => {
            doc
              .html(footer, { x: 10, y: doc.internal.pageSize.height - 50 })
              .then(() => {
                cont = cont + 1;
                if (cont <= totalPages) {
                  addHeaderAndFooterToPage(); // Chama a função recursivamente para a próxima    
          página
                } else {
                  doc.save("final.pdf");
                  console.log("acabou o loop");
                }
              });
          });
        };

        addHeaderAndFooterToPage(); // Inicia o processo
      });
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't better first to add the header, then to add the div and then to add the footer?

Or other idea - to wrap the content in a container or to use body element and to parse the hole content at once.